# CoreData's performBlock: and faulting

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using the performBlock: and performBlockAndWait: methods to execute fetch requests on my context on a read only database (it is packaged with my app so never written to).

Am I supposed to be wrapping every NSManagedObject accessor inside performBlockAndWait: as well? - that'd be pretty messy. I'm currently getting crashes whenever CoreData is faulting a one-to-many relationship while CoreData's private queue is doing an execute with performBlock:

Something like:

```
NSManagedObject* alreadyFetchedObject = ...;
NSArray* alreadyFetchedObject.otherObjects; // Crashes here on main thread (no performBlock wrapped around accessing otherObjects)
```

.

```
[context performBlockAndWait:^{
    // Currently executing here on CoreData's own queue
    result = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
}];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. Maybe with the exception for managed objects which have been associated to a context which is executed on the main thread. But for clarity, I would always wrap accesses into `performBlock:`. Be careful with `performBlockAndWait:` - this is error prone for dead locks.

Additionally, when you have statements like this:

```
NSManagedObject* alreadyFetchedObject = ...;
```

and access `alreadyFetchedObject` later, you need to ensure that the corresponding managed object context still exists. Thus, *always* accessing managed objects with `performBlock:` or `performBlockAndWait:` reminds you not to accidentally delete the context ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, too bad because it's going to look extremely ugly with perform blocks around literally everything :(

Comment: You can relax this safely when you *know* and *require* your context is associated to the main thread: for example, when initializing cells in a table view, e.g.:  `User* user = [self.userModels objectAtIndex:0];`. Here, `self.userModels` is an array of managed objects solely for the purpose to be handled in the main thread, for displaying it in a table view. Then in this scenario, using `performBlockAndWait:` would be overkill, and unnecessary anyway, since if it not were the main thread, you couldn't display a User anyway.

Comment: My real world example is searching on a different thread and then presenting the data on the main thread in a table, then showing more info when selected. The prefetched things like cell titles work fine, but the others are the issue. I suppose I could fetch it again when its tapped, on the main thread via it's managed object id (this is pretty much the only separate db thread process)

Comment: Note: You cannot use managed objects from thread A, in a different Thread B. Please read: **Track Changes in Other Threads Using Notifications** in [Concurrency with Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1). So, you are right when you say you need to refetch those managed objects using the relevant context.

Comment: When I say thread I mean the one that coredata uses under the hood when you use performBlock: - also its read only so there's no changes to track

Comment: Yes, I meant the same: the thread, or better execution context, where the context executes its methods. If you fetch managed objects from a relation using a context which executes on a private queue, you cannot display these in a table view, since they must be fetched using a context associated to the main thread.

Comment: That's true to some extent, but you can access the pre faulted fields